# Marginal conditional mean of two dimensional Brownian motion, using more than one time point.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

EDIT: I found the error! I do not think this question is relevant for anyone, but I cannot find out how to delete it - please feel free to if you have the read this and have the option. I have indicated in the question where the error is.

Consider a standard two-dimensional Wiener process $(W^1,W^2)$, but with correlation $\rho$ between them. What I am trying to do is find the mean and variance for one of them at some deterministic time $T$, conditional on the other at both time $T$ and $T-1$. I get non-intuitive results and hoped you guys could help clairify. My standing theory is that I've made some mistake, but I can't find it.

We can derive that (this is standard/using independent increments)
$$\rho_{11} := Corr(W^1_T,W^1_{T-1}) = \sqrt{\frac{T-1}{T}}$$ and $$\rho_{21}:=Corr(W^2_T,W^1_{T-1}) = \rho \sqrt{\frac{T-1}{T}}.$$ Note the relation $\rho_{21}=\rho \cdot \rho_{11}$.

Now let us derive the conditional distribution of $W^2(T)$ using results from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions).
Summing up we found 
$$(W^2(T),W^1(T),W^1(T-1)) \sim N(0,\Sigma)$$
where
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  \rho & \rho_{21}  \\ 
\rho  & 1 & \rho_{11} \\
\rho_{21}  & \rho_{11}  & 1  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
as argued above.
 Then set 
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_{11} = {} & 1  \\ 
\Sigma_{12} = {} &  (\rho_{RS} ,\rho_{SS}  ) \\ 
\Sigma_{21} = {} &  (\rho_{RS} , \rho_{SS}  )' \\ 
\Sigma_{22} = {} &  
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho   \\
\rho  & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
The error is here! $\Sigma_{22}$ is not what it should be.

We get 
\begin{equation*}
\det ( \Sigma_{22})  =  1- \rho^2
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_{22}^{-1} = 
\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\rho \\
-\rho  & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and using the observation $\rho_{21} = \rho  \cdot \rho_{11}$  we get 
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} ={} &  \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}   \bigl ( \rho_{21} -\rho \cdot \rho_{11},  \rho_{11} -\rho\cdot  \rho_{21} \bigr ) \\
             = {} & \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}    \bigl (  0, (1-\rho^2)   \rho_{11 } \bigr )  \\
              = {} &  \bigl (  0,    \rho_{11 } \bigr ) 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 \Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1}  \Sigma_{21}= {} &  \frac{\rho_{21}}{1- \rho^2 } \cdot ( \rho_{21}- \rho \cdot \rho_{11}) + \frac{\rho_{11} }{1- \rho^2} \cdot (\rho_{11}  - \rho\cdot \rho_{21} ) \\
 = {} &  \frac{\rho_{11} }{1- \rho^2} \cdot ( (1-\rho^2) \rho_{11}  ) \\
 = {}  & \rho_{11}. 
\end{align*}

This means that 
$$E[W^2_T \lvert W^1_{T}=w_2, W^1(T-1) =w_1 ] = \rho_{11} w_1$$ and 
$$Var(W^2_T \lvert W^1_{T}=w_2, W^1(T-1) =w_1 ) =  \rho_{11},$$ by the formula for finding the marginal distribution.

As mentioned I'm finding this result really strange, so, first of all: Are there anything wrong with the derivation? 
If not, what is the intuition behind that all information from $W^1_T$ say seems to magically dissapear ? Even worse the parameter measuring correlation (which would be my guess would measure the information, were it $0$ I would say there were none) is not even in the formulas!